# Evaluating $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(an+b)^2+(cm+d)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me with evaluating

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(an+b)^2+(cm+d)^2}$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are real numbers?

I was able to evaluate the summation with respect to $n$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(an+b)^2+(cm+d)^2}=\frac{i\pi \left(\cot \left( \frac{\pi(b+i(cm+d))}{a}\right)-\cot \left( \frac{\pi(b-i(cm+d))}{a}\right)\right)}{2a(cm+d)},$$

but I couldn't compute the summation with respect to $m$.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't understand why it diverges. Could you add a bit more detail?

Comment: Converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This double series **diverges**.

Basically this reduces to the divergence of $\sum_{m,n>0}(m^2+n^2)^{-1}$, which is easy to show: $$\sum_{0<m,n\leqslant N}\frac1{m^2+n^2}\geqslant\sum_{0<m,n\leqslant N}\frac1{2\max\{m,n\}^2}=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{2k-1}{2k^2}\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty.$$

The reduction to this case is as follows.  The sum is invariant w.r.t. $a\mapsto-a$ (the same change is done by replacing $n$ with $-n$) and similarly $b\mapsto-b$, $c\mapsto-c$, $d\mapsto-d$; also w.r.t. $b\mapsto b-ka$ for any integer $k$ (replace $n$ with $n-k$) and similarly $d\mapsto d-kc$.

Thus we may assume that $0<b<a$ and $0<d<c$. But then $$(an+b)^2+(cm+d)^2\leqslant\max\{a,c\}^2\big((n+1)^2+(m+1)^2\big),$$ and the part $\sum_{0\leqslant m,n<N}$ of the sum is at least $\max\{a,c\}^{-2}\sum_{0<m,n\leqslant N}(m^2+n^2)^{-1}$.